# Ubuntu Server 16.04 with dropbear

Tags: encryption, ubuntu-16.04, lvm, dropbear

Trying to get Dropbear to work with Ubuntu Server 16.04 to enable for remote disk decryption to.

I am following this [tutorial](https://stinkyparkia.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/remote-unlocking-luks-encrypted-lvm-using-dropbear-ssh-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-1-with-static-ipst/)

But failing at this step: `sudo cp /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa ~/id_rsa_dropbear`

as the file: `/etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa` dose not exit on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Any help would be great.

Thanks
alexis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to figure it out in the end. I ended up writing a blog post about it here [Unlocking Ubuntu Server 16 encrypted LUKS using Dropbear SSH](http://blog.netpacket.co.uk/category/linux/). The post I wrote is very heavily based from the answer I found here [SSH to decrypt encrypted LVM during headless server boot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/ssh-to-decrypt-encrypted-lvm-during-headless-server-boot) and all did was change the version 16 specific parts.

cheers
alexis